# Adminbar Missing "Edit Page"

Tags: pages, code, admin-bar, quick-edit, bug

I'm encountering a problem that involves that my Admin bar doesn't show the "Edit Page" on pages I visit on my site. Instead for some odd reason it show "Edit Category" instead on supposed page.

Does anyone know what might cause this? I checked on another thread about putting

`<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` 
in the `footer.php` but this didn't work for me.

I did it like this:

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:
I forgot to mention, that I first created a template which was a copy of another one, the only change was that it called a different function. That function was a copy from another, basically what it did was how much text it showed in a post. I also created a different loop.php(named loop2.php) so it could work with this template.
So the conclusion of this was that you could choose now a new different template for your page (imagine that the original name was: *template* and I created *template2*.

The changes in **query.php** for the function **wp_reset_query()** which I did after the bug emerged was:

**from:**

```
function wp_reset_query() {

    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

**to:**

```
function wp_reset_query() {
unset($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

I read somewhere on a forum that `unset($GLOBALS['wp_query']);` would help me..

Update #2: 
The code for the original template:

```
   <?php 
    /*
    Template Name: Blog List
    */
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <?php tie_breadcrumbs() ?>

        <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div id="post-0" class="post not-found post-listing">
                <h1 class="post-title"><?php _e( 'Ej hittad', 'tie' ); ?></h1>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="page-head">
            <h1 class="page-title">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h1>
        </div>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $get_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);  ?>
        <?php tie_include( 'post-head' ); // Get Post Head template ?>  
        <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php //Above Post Banner
        if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_above"][0] ) ){
            if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="ads-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_above"][0]) .'</div>';
            else tie_banner('banner_above' , '<div class="ads-post">' , '</div>' );
        }
        ?>

        <?php $cat_query = '';
        if ( !empty( $get_meta["tie_blog_cats"][0] ) ) $cat_query = '&cat=' . $get_meta["tie_blog_cats"][0] ; ?>
        <?php query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page='. $cat_query); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );  ?>
        <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>

        <?php //Below Post Banner
        if( empty( $get_meta["tie_hide_below"][0] ) ){
            if( !empty( $get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0] ) ) echo '<div class="ads-post">' .htmlspecialchars_decode($get_meta["tie_banner_below"][0]) .'</div>';
            else tie_banner('banner_below' , '<div class="ads-post">' , '</div>' );
        }
        ?>

        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
    </div><!-- .content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As I mentioned in the text I did a copy of this one to create a second template.. The copy used a different function. So instead of `the_content();` it used `blog();` which was a copy of `the_content();` except that it had a different value, the value determined how much text it would show in a post in my site.

Comment: If for some reason you're messing with the main query, you'd need to `wp_reset_query()` *before* `wp_footer()`, since the adminbar script outputs at `wp_footer()`. That said: can you please provide more context? What is the code that is impacting the main query? What is the context: is this a custom page template?

Comment: I did an update on the case if you're interested @Chip Bennett

Comment: Wait: you're **modifying core files**? Don't do that. Ever. Also, please include your **actual template code**, as relevant.

Comment: Template code included, thanks for your time! @Chip Bennett

Answer (score 1):

1. Undo your core-file change
2. Replace `query_posts()` with a proper call to [`new WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for your secondary query loop.

Your admin bar issues will auto-magically disappear.

Comment: Hmm, this will be the first time for me doing this so..

could something like this work?: <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=any' ); ?> @Chip Bennett